# Column_stacking arbitrary amounts of data in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list of "spectral" objects that have "ydata" attributes and I need to column stack all the ydata together.

I can iterate through all the objects but I have to somehow create an array of the same length so that I can stack.

Here is a barebones version of what I have:

```
import numpy as np

class Spectrum(object):

  def __init__(self, ydata):
    self.ydata = ydata

spec = {}

spec[1] = Spectrum([1,2,3])
spec[2] = Spectrum([4,5,6])

array = np.empty(len(spec[1].ydata))

for i in range(1,len(spec)+1):
    array = np.column_stack((array,spec[i].ydata))

print(array)
```

So the above works, but the first column of array is always the empty (random) values.

I know there has to be an easy way to do this but I am just missing it.

One option that I thought of is to start with:

```
array = spec[1].ydata
```

then move into the for-loop but that doesn't seem right since that assumes there is a spec[1].

The desired output would be:

```
>>>array
>>>[[1 4]
    [2 5]
    [3 6]]
```

Comment: Repeatedly concatenating arrays is discouraged.  It is slow compared to collecting arrays in a list and doing one concatenate at the end.  And as you found it is harder to create a start value.  But you could try `array = np.empty((len(spec[1].ydata, 0)))`, a 2d array with size 0 column dimension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that all your instances of `Spectrum` have the same ydata-length, I would go with a simple list comprehension:

```
array = np.array([spec[i+1].ydata for i in range(len(spec))])
print(array)
```

output:

```
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]
```

**EDIT**:

I took another look at the desired output, in that case it would be

```
array = np.array([spec[i+1].ydata for i in range(len(spec))]).T
```

and

```
[[1 4]
 [2 5]
 [3 6]]
```

**EDIT**:

I wrote a small test program to compare the performances of `np.array().T` and `np.column_stack()` against each other:

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import Timer

class Spectrum(object):

  def __init__(self, ydata):
    self.ydata = ydata

def create_by_array():
  return np.array([spec[i+1].ydata for i in range(len(spec))]).T

def create_by_column_stack():
  return np.column_stack([spec[i+1].ydata for i in range(len(spec))])


I = 1000
spec = {i: Spectrum([j for j in range(3*i,3*(i+1))]) for i in range(1,I+1)}

t1 = Timer(
  """create_by_array()""",
  setup="""from __main__ import create_by_array"""
  )
res1 = t1.repeat(10,1000)

t2 = Timer(
  """create_by_column_stack()""",
  setup="""from __main__ import create_by_column_stack"""
  )
res2 = t2.repeat(10,1000)

print(
  'Results of the two tests:   ',
  '{:5}, {:5}, {:5}'.format('min','mean','max')
  )
print(
  'With np.array and transpose:',
  '{:5.3}, {:5.3}, {:5.3}'.format(np.min(res1), np.mean(res1),np.max(res1))
)
print(
  'With np.column_stack():     ',
  '{:5.4}, {:5.4}, {:5.4}'.format(np.min(res2), np.mean(res2),np.max(res2))
)
```

The program first produces a dict of 1000 `Spectrum` instances and then times the two methods 10 x 1000 times. Here are the results:

```
('Results of the two tests:   ', 'min  , mean , max  ')
('With np.array and transpose:', '0.687, 0.709, 0.742')
('With np.column_stack():     ', '3.982, 4.367, 5.263')
```

As you can see, `np.array().T` method is about 5 times faster than the `np.column_stack()`. I'm not entirely sure why that is, but according to the [numpy column_stack documentation page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html),

> Take a sequence of 1-D arrays and stack them as columns to make a
>   single 2-D array. 2-D arrays are stacked as-is, just like with hstack.
>   1-D arrays are turned into 2-D columns first.

This sounds a lot like every individual sub-list is first turned into an `ndarray`, while `np.array()` only creates the final array. The transposing of the matrix is very fast, as it does not do any re-arranging in memory. See for instance [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html). I hope this clears it up.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Using the above, however, array becomes a generator object, which sklearn.decomposition.pca.fit() isn't happy with.
Interestingly enough if I use np.column_stack instead of np.array, and don't do the _transform_, I get the desired output.  Why does one yield a generator while the other returns an array?

Comment: @chaugen1 My code returns a `numpy.ndarray`, not a generator. Did you run exactly the code that I posted?

Comment: OK my mistake.  I missed the square brackets around the array() argument.  So what would be the benefit of building an array and then transposing it, rather than starting with the numpy.column_stack()?  Thank you so much for your help!